# Android - Receiving UDP packets in different ports

Tags: android, sockets, udp

I'm in a trouble receiving UDP packets in Android.

I'm receiving them form my server.The problem is that I need to change my udp port every 3 minutes, so I send a request to my server from my new port, and then keep blocked in the socket.receive() method. My server send the packet to that new port, but the problem is that my App doesn't receive it although it's in the receive() method and in the correct port.

Before this I tried to be always listening and sending in the same port, and the app worked fine.

Thanks in advance for the help

Comment: *Why* do you need to change your UDP port every three minutes?

Comment: I want to keep the communication even if the device's IP changes, and I need to keep alive the entry in the NAT for that UDP port, so each 3-4 minutes I send a refresh packet, to keep alive the entry and I send it through a new socket: socket = new DatagramSocket(); and then I start listening for responses in the new socket. With that refresh packet the server updates the new Ip and port for the device and can send the future packets to it

Comment: That doesn't explain why you need to change the port every three minutes.